# Google blogger in objective-c/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, blogger

How can i post blog on google blogger in my iPhone application. Is there any open source project?

Comment: http://buzz.blogger.com/2009/09/theres-app-for-that.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no narive Ojective-C framework aa far as I know, but you can do it using the Blogger Protocol API.  It does mean you'll have to do some of the dirty work, but it should work for you.  If you have problems with it you can always post them here on Stack Overflow and I or someone else will try to help.